# Monitoring multiple server stats in React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, react-redux

I have multiple pods running on my Kubernetes cluster and I have a "core app" built with react from which I want to get CPU & Memory usage stats.

Right now I am testing using a very simple setup where I have a local node app using socket.io to stream the time (based on this [tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/))

However, with one component which looks like the following, I am able to get real time updates from the server.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import {StatsCPUWrapper} from './statsCPU.style'
const ENDPOINT = process.env.STATS_ENDPOINT || "http://127.0.0.1:4001";


function StatsCPUComp() {
    const [cpustats, setCPUstats] = useState("");
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
      socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
        setCPUstats(data);
      });
      // Clean up the effect
      return () => socket.disconnect();
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <StatsCPUWrapper>
      <p>
        It's <time dateTime={cpustats}>{cpustats}</time>
      </p>
      </StatsCPUWrapper>
    );
  }
  
  export default StatsCPUComp;
```

What I am now trying to do is have 3 or more of those components (depends on the list I get from my backend) to "subscribe" to multiple servers at the same time.

Here's my "projects list" component which gets the stats from the initial state and renders all the details:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {create, remove} from '../../features/projects/projectSlice'
import {ProjectWrapper} from './project.style'
import StatsCPUComp from './stats/statsCPU'

export function ProjectComp() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const projects = useSelector((state) => state.projects)

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    const handleAction = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (
        <ProjectWrapper>
            <div className="projects">
                <div className="row">
                    {projects.map((projects) => (
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div class="card project-card">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-4 project-text">
                                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                                {' '}
                                                <Link to={`/projects/` + projects.id}>{projects.name}</Link>
                                            </h5>

                                            <p class="card-text">Owner: {projects.owner}</p>
                                            <p class="card-text">{projects.email}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-4 projects-stats">
                                            <StatsCPUComp />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-4 projects-stats"></div>
                                        <div className="col-4 projects-stats"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br></br>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProjectWrapper>
    )
}
```

Right now the "time" from the stats component is being added on my last project component (makes sense since I did not implement any approach yet to map that too).

Any ideas on how I can have a different stats component for each of my "projects" where each one connects to a provided endpoint ? (I can pass all of the endpoints as env variables)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the implementation I did to make it work. (Not sure if it's ideal so please feel free to make any suggestions)

I added "endpoint" to state.projects which holds the data I get from my backend.

Then in my "projects list" component mentioned shown in the question, I pass projects (from state.projects) as props

```
<StatsCPUComp props={projects}/>
```

I then destructure it and pass it to my useEffect() in the stats component as follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'
import {StatsCPUWrapper} from './statsCPU.style'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

let ENDPOINTS = []
let PROJECTS = []
function StatsCPUComp(...props) {
    const [cpustats, setCPUstats] = useState('')

  let endpoints = {...props}
  let endpoints_2 = {...endpoints[0]}


    useEffect(() => {
    let socketlist = []
    console.log(endpoints[0].props.endpoint)
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoints[0].props.endpoint);

      socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
        setCPUstats(data);
    });
    return () => socket.disconnect();

    }, [cpustats])

    return (
    <>
 
        <StatsCPUWrapper>
            <p>
                It's <time dateTime={cpustats}>{cpustats}</time>
            </p>
        </StatsCPUWrapper>

    </>
    )
}

export default StatsCPUComp
```

It seems to be working fine, however please do provide any suggestions since I might not be following an optimal approach (Performance and scalability wise)